# Am I abusing MongoDB's documents?

Tags: mongodb

I have an online shop, kind of like eBay.
There are sellers and the sellers products. Each seller can have 0 or more products that he is willing to sell. Normally, there are around 30 per person.

Right now I have one document per person, and that document contains the users info and a sub-document that contains every product he is selling (including all the photos that the product has, prices, tags, etc).

Am I abusing MongoDB's documents? Should I be doing it in another way?

Comment: @costa Buyers can see all products (so they can buy them). I'm just not that used to embedding everything in a single document, and I'm worried for the implications it could lead. What if a seller decides he wants to sell 5000 items? Could MongoDB handle that?

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/

Comment: I'm calling this a duplicate. The embed vs. reference question has been asked in many different ways.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you move your products into a separate collection (e.g. `products`). Embedded documents should only be used when the document you're embedding is small, or the amount is limited. Additionally, having products in a separate collection will allow for [greater flexibility](http://openmymind.net/Multiple-Collections-Versus-Embedded-Documents/) when selecting documents.

In your case, you would likely be sometimes selecting a single product (e.g. a view for viewing a single product) so it would make sense to keep products in a separate collection.

Comment: That helped me a lot. So I should be actually storing all the products in another collection as I'll need to show random products, query them in a specific order, or with specific tags (show me all red products, or, show me all products heavier than 2kg). Thank you! Let's see if others can add something.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest moving products to a separate collection.

MongoDB data schemas are best when based on the usage requirements. In this case, a user browsing products is going to very rarely be interested in all the products that a different user is selling. Usually, they're going to be interested in products that match search criteria about price and item description or item title.

So imagine a search for the most recently posted items given your proposed data schema. Your query will have to search through every `user`'s array of `product` subdocuments and check the `timePosted`. Whereas a `product` collection could easily have an index on `timePosted` and not require touching unnecessary (`user` and each `user`'s other `products`) documents.

The use case for seeing a single product page is also important to consider and also indicates using a separate `product` collection.

Even when you do need to show `product`s that a particular `user` posted, it will not be difficult in a `product` collection to search by `user_id`.